# css - centered div top disappears when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have a div box that is centered vertical and horizontal.

When I resize the window to a size smaller than the height of the div, the div partially disappears and the scroll doesn't allow me to scroll up to show me the missing part.

How can I fix this issue?

CSS

```
#main{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    border:20px solid #000;
}
#container{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<div id="container">I want to see this when scrolling up</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skorpion/buwwypu0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u want to use your css, use a media query like this:

```
@media (max-height: 200px) {
    #main {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

add this at the end of your css. Should do the job.

Comment: Yes that's true, one of the solution is using media jquery, so I don't need to answer it then :D